# highcharts candlestick update every 5, 15 seconds

Tags: highcharts

after some time distance becomes increasingly between candles

Comment: You can see my chart on  https://jsfiddle.net/ruit/6uugo2tw/6/

Comment: What is the question here? Each loop will not be 1000 milliseconds after a previous one because you are setting 1 second interval, but time of executing code in a single loop will increase overall time between new points being added.